# Ping on Android in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ping

I am currently trying to ping another device from my Unity application. I have tried both `UnityEngine.Ping` and `System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping`, but neither work correctly on Android. `UnityEngine.Ping` already fails on Windows if the target is not in the same network (I get a response from my own PC and another that is in the ethernet, but not from my phone which is on wifi). I *do* get a response from the phone if I use `System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping` on Windows.

On Adroid, each has a different problem:

`UnityEngine.Ping`: No exception, but the Ping reports `isDone` after a second, but the `time` property is `-1` (which indicates that there was no response yet). The `timeout` was set to 45 seconds, just to be sure.

```
UnityEngine.Ping ping = new UnityEngine.Ping(remoteIP);

float timer = 0;
while (timer <= timeout && !ping.isDone) {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
}

if (ping.time < 0 || ping.time >= timeout) {
    //do failure stuff
} else {
    //do success stuff
}

ping.DestroyPing();
```

`System.Net.Networkinfo.Ping`: I tried both `Send` and `SendAsync`. The former throws an `InvalidOperationException`, the latter invokes the `PingCompleted` callback immediately and throws a `NullReferenceException`. Both versions work perfectly fine on Windows.

Send:

```
Thread pingThread = new Thread(() => {
    using (System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()) {

        PingReply reply = ping.Send(remoteIP, Mathf.RoundToInt(timeout * 1000));

        if (reply?.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
            //do success stuff
        } else {
            //do failure stuff
        }
    }
});
pingThread.Start();
```

(I also tried calling it on the main thread. It *did* block on Windows, but didn't on Android, and threw the same Exception: `InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.`)

SendAsync:

```
using (System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()) {

    ping.PingCompleted += (sender, args) => {
        if (args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
            //do success stuff
        } else {
            //do failure stuff
        }
    };

    ping.SendAsync(remoteIP, Mathf.RoundToInt(timeout * 1000));
}
```

The  `NullRefereneException` is thrown in the line `if (args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {`.

Can anybody here tell me what I am doing wrong? Or what else I could try?

**Edit:** It does not necessarily have to be an actual ICMP ping. I just need to know if an address is reachable, so alternative solutions are also very welcome.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions?

Comment: Do I need extra permissions for a ping? I already (successfully) open TCP and UDP connections in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was specifically IP 8.8.8.8 (google DNS) that never responded to ping on Android and cause timeout. Switched to another IP would solve this problem, for example, these are the ones currently working for me:

- 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare)
- 1.0.0.1 (Cloudflare)
- 4.2.2.2
- 208.67.222.222 (Open DNS)
- 208.67.220.220 (Open DNS)

And it's true `UnityEngine.Ping` also always have `isDone==true` right after created, one way to identify the ping actually finish is to check `pinger.time > 0`, since `-1` mean the ping still in progress.

Answer (score 0):

In commercial projet, we usually send message with timeStamp to server by TCP socket, then receive message from server, in this case the ping = (Server_timeStamp - Client_timeStamp).

Comment: I don't want to ping a specific server that has our software running, I want to be able to ping an arbitrary device.